# I can’t find out which os is better for me

Tags: windows, macos, laptop

I am going to buy a new laptop next summer and I hesitate between macOS and Windows. I will mainly be programming (I don’t know which language, but it won’t be 3D graphics or anything like that. Probably websites or mobile apps). I know that I can only develop Ios apps on iMacs, but I still don’t know if I’ll often make that kind of code. I’ll maybe play little video games like Minecraft but really occasionally. My maximum budget is 2,5k €, sh should I buy a Macbook, or look for a windows pc, and get VMWare on it?

Comment: ***asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation*** is specifically [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Please note that macOS is only licensed for use on Apple Mac hardware. It's a violation of the license agreement to run it on a non-Apple PC, even in a VM.

Comment: You can get a Mac & run both macOS & Windows on it, **legally**. That's your only option if you want both. You can't run macOS on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: @Tetsujin so i have to run a Windows virtual machine on the mac? Or is there a way to choose either Mac or Windows at the startup?

Comment: You can do either. Boot to it or run as a VM. Google Boot Camp for the first, Parallels or VMWare Fusion for the second.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for your answers. Mu last question is: isn’t that handicapping to use macOS for many things in programmation, or using Windows as second OS is ok and I won’t encounter any problem?

Comment: Use whichever one suits the task. If you have Win in VM you don't even need to reboot to swap.

Comment: @Tetsujin that wasn’t exactly the answer I was expecting for... I want to know if the experience on windows 10 on a mac is the same as on any windows laptop (like acer, asus, dell, hp, etc...) and if it works well (no lags, no compatibility of softwares’ problem)

Comment: Please do some research. This is a common subject & there is a lot of data on it.

Comment: @Tetsujin ok. Ty for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to get a WHOLE LOT of BS opinion and very little actual substance with a question like this.  It is not unlike asking 'should I be Muslim or Christian?'
I wouldn't even trust ME ;^)  EVERYONE has a skewed opinion.

***VERY FEW*** people are an expert on both platforms and will rattle off anecdotal crap about the other because of things they experienced 15+ years ago and know nothing about.

I am a software engineer (25+ years) and code on both platforms for different reasons.
**I love/hate both of them.**  They both have plenty to love and hate.

As you mention, if you are EVER going to want to produce iOS applications.  **You need a mac**.  This is the one and only reason I have a macbook pro in my arsenal.

If you are ever going to want to write native desktop apps (or games) that can be used by +80% of the market, **You need a PC**.

***Coding web stuff is equally good on both.***

If you aren't sure, I just bought a quad core 10th gen 17 laptop with 16gb of ram and 4k display for less than 1K.  If you absolutely end up hating windows, you can drop Linux on there for free.  If you aren't sure, why spend the money?

Both boxes are polished and run well.
Both boxes support unix interfaces and applications (BSD for mac, WSL for windows)

Apple will force you to stay in their ecosystem/playground but my mac loving friends are perfectly happy with that.. and yes.. these friends are super-smart so I respect their opinions.

Now, I must prepare for a barrage of comments from windows and mac zealots... this should be fun.